# How to inspect values of settings in Seq[Setting[_]]?

Tags: scala, sbt, twirl

I'm trying to read the values of `twirlSettings` defined in [SbtTwirl](https://github.com/playframework/twirl/blob/master/sbt-twirl/src/main/scala/play/twirl/sbt/SbtTwirl.scala).

Is there a way to do it? Perhaps using `sbt inspect`? Or is there any other way? I need to read the values as I'm trying to find out why my Twirl templates don't get compiled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`twirlSettings`, as such, is not a key that you can `sbt inspect`. It is a `Seq[Setting[_]]`. However, you can inspect the individual settings it produces. For example:

```
> inspect compile:compileTemplates::sourceDirectories
```

to inspect what is produced by [line 40](https://github.com/playframework/twirl/blob/d5b01d71dc76e365d5a1b40549556b3754a4d779/sbt-twirl/src/main/scala/play/twirl/sbt/SbtTwirl.scala#L40):

```
sourceDirectories in compileTemplates := Seq(sourceDirectory.value / "twirl"),
```

Comment: `show compile:compileTemplates::sourceDirectories` to display the contents

Answer (score 0):

The other answer's fine, but there's a little bit more involved approach using `consoleProject` or `eval`.

See the following session in `consoleProject`:

```
[root]> help consoleProject
Starts the Scala interpreter with the sbt and the build definition on the classpath and useful imports.

[root]> consoleProject
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
import sbt._
import Keys._
import _root_.com.typesafe.sbteclipse.plugin.EclipsePlugin._
import _root_.gilt.DependencyGraph._
import _root_.net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin._
import _root_.com.typesafe.sbt.SbtGit._
import _root_.com.github.tototoshi.sbt.musical.Plugin._
import _root_.com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin._
import _root_.play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl.autoImport._
import _root_.sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.CorePlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin
import _root_.play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl
import currentState._
import extracted._
import cpHelpers._
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> SbtTwirl
res0: play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl.type = play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl
```

Having access to `SbtTwirl` and using Scala you can do whatever you'd ever want, but be careful with your guessing since life in `consoleProject` might not be that easy as it's in `build.sbt` - no `.value` macros at your fingertips. You're in Scala world, though.

```
scala> SbtTwirl.twirlSettings.foreach { s => println(s) }
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,Select(twirlCompileTemplates),This),includeFilter)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,38)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,Select(twirlCompileTemplates),This),excludeFilter)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,39)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,Select(twirlCompileTemplates),This),sourceDirectories)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,40)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,Select(twirlCompileTemplates),This),sources)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,42)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,Global,This,This),watchSources)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,48)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,Select(twirlCompileTemplates),This),target)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,50)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,This,This),twirlCompileTemplates)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,52)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,This,This),sourceGenerators)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,54)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,This,This),managedSourceDirectories)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,55)
```

Using `eval` might be useful, too.

```
[root]> help eval
eval <expression>

    Evaluates the given Scala expression and prints the result and type.

[root]> eval SbtTwirl.twirlSettings
[info] ans: Seq[sbt.Setting[_]] = List(setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,Select(twirlCompileTemplates),This),includeFilter)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,38), setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,Select(twirlCompileTemplates),This),excludeFilter)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,39), setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,Select(twirlCompileTemplates),This),sourceDirectories)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,40), setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,Select(twirlCompileTemplates),This),sources)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,42), setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,Global,This,This),watchSources)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,48), setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,Select(twirlCompileTemplates),This),target)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,50), setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,This,This),twirlCompileTemplates)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,52), setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,This,This),sourceGenerators)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,54), setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,This,This),managedSourceDirectories)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,55))

[root]> eval SbtTwirl.twirlSettings.foreach { e => println(e) }
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,Select(twirlCompileTemplates),This),includeFilter)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,38)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,Select(twirlCompileTemplates),This),excludeFilter)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,39)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,Select(twirlCompileTemplates),This),sourceDirectories)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,40)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,Select(twirlCompileTemplates),This),sources)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,42)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,Global,This,This),watchSources)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,48)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,Select(twirlCompileTemplates),This),target)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,50)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,This,This),twirlCompileTemplates)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,52)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,This,This),sourceGenerators)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,54)
setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,This,This),managedSourceDirectories)) at LinePosition((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala,55)
[info] ans: Unit = null
```